# How to allow user to query collection but only access certain results in collection?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Working in firebase and setting up complex (to me) rules for the first time.

I have a collection of Children which have a property "parentId". I only want certain roles and users to read this table. Specifically, I want any coach or referee role to be able to read as well as the parent of any child.

I believe that the problem lies in "data.child('parentId').val() === auth.uid" at the collection level .read. I feel like I perfectly followed the example here, but it still isn't working: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/data.html

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong in my security rules?

I am aware that security rules do not filter and I do not believe that this is an example of that particular problem because my query is specifically limiting the results to what I am attempting to allow through security rules (though I may be mistaken).

Here is current security rules. The comments should explain what I'm going for:

```
"children": {
      // give ability of any coach or referee to read any child. Give refs ability to write to any child. Allow parent to query for their own children.
      ".read": "(data.child('parentId').val() === auth.uid) ||(root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() === 'coach') || (root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() === 'referee')",
      ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() === 'referee'",
      ".indexOn": ["parentId", "isApproved"],
      "$child": {
        // give a parent read and write access to only their specific children.
        ".read": "root.child('children').child($child).child('parentId').val() === auth.uid",
        ".write": "root.child('children').child($child).child('parentId').val() === auth.uid"
      }
 }
```

In my code I am doing a query of all Children by their parentId. Here is my javascript that fails with "Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.":

```
factory.getChildrenByParent = function(parentId){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            childrenRef.orderByChild('parentId').equalTo(parentId)
                .once('value', function(childrenResponse){
                    var children = childrenResponse.val();
                    processChildren(children);
                    resolve(children);
                },
                function(err){
                    if(err){
                        reject(err);
                    }
                })

        })
    }
```

The comments should explain what I'm going for. The problem is that a user can not query the Children by the parents id (which is equal to auth.uid).
They can query one off with this:

```
factory.getChildById = function(id){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            childrenRef.orderByKey().equalTo(id)
                .once('value', function(childResult){
                    var childObjects = childResult.val();

                    processChildren(childObjects);
                    var child = Utilities.getFirst(childObjects);
                    resolve(child);

                },
                function(err){
                    if(err){
                        reject(err);
                    }
                })
        })
    }
```

I've tried using the simulator but I can't figure out the syntax for .orderByChild('parentId').equalTo(parentId) and Chrome dev tools network doesn't show any activity when I fire this...

Answer (score 7):

You might want to read the section of the [Firebase documentation on "Rules are not filters"](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter) again.

> Rules are applied in an atomic manner. That means that a read or write operation is failed immediately if there isn't a rule at that location or at a parent location that grants access. Even if every child path is accessible, reading at the parent location will fail completely. Consider this structure:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "records": {
      "rec1": {
        ".read": true
      },
      "rec2": {
        ".read": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Without understanding that rules are evaluated atomically, it might seem like fetching the /records/ path would return rec1 but not rec2. The actual result, however, is an error:

```
ref.child("records").once("value", function(snap) {
  // success method is not called
}, function(err) {
  // error callback triggered with PERMISSION_DENIED
});
```

> Since the read operation at /records/ is atomic, and there's no read rule that grants access to all of the data under /records/, this will throw a `PERMISSION_DENIED` error. If we evaluate this rule in the security simulator in our App Dashboard, we can see that the read operation was denied:

```
Attempt to read /records with auth=Success(null)
/
/records
No .read rule allowed the operation.
Read was denied.
```

> The operation was denied because no read rule allowed access to the /records/ path, but note that the rule for rec1 was never evaluated because it wasn't in the path we requested. To fetch rec1, we would need to access it directly:

```
ref.child("records/rec1").once("value", function(snap) {
  // SUCCESS!
}, function(err) {
  // error callback is not called
});
```

In other words: **you can only perform a query on a location when you have read access to that location**.

Some questions about the same:

- [Can't read data from Firebase after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842287/cant-read-data-from-firebase-after-authentication/34846262#34846262)
- [Workaround for Firebase's "Rules Are Not Filters" constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914364/workaround-for-firebases-rules-are-not-filters-constraint)
- [How to allow read/write objects only to authenticated user with Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827655/how-to-allow-read-write-objects-only-to-authenticated-user-with-firebase/34880035#34880035)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response Frank. In your example above, what if the query was only specifically looking for records that met the security rules? To modify your example: 
{
  "rules": {
    "records": {
              ".read": "data.child('read').val() === true"
      }
    }
  }
} 
   and a query like so: ref.child('records').orderByChild('read').equalTo(true) This is the equivalent to what I am doing. As stated in my question, I do not believe that I am using security rules to filter.